# How can I use Query notification and what are the requirement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, service-broker

I want to use Query notification in my app to get the notification from database for updated data, so that app will fire the query to get updated data instead of monitoring the database for every 5 sec. I am using ms sql server 2012 express edition and Am using apache tomcat server to deploy my application(webMathematica), I use user custom tag of jsp to embed my application to tomcat server.

I need to configure client application to send notification request to database, but I have no idea about how to configure my client application to use query notification.

Suggest me good material to use query notification.